# : Trying to open all excel files in a folder, code skips everything after Do While FileName <> ""

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm a bit of a VBA noob, but trying to learn.

I need my macro to open all excel files (hundreds) in a folder and extract information, to summarize all in one sheet.

After a long search, I found a sample code on msdn.microsoft.com that seemed to fit my needs:

```
    Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Test_Summary_Folder"

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
        ' It can span multiple rows.
        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A9:C9")

        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
        ' be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
    ' data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I'd like to change some parts like copying to a sheet within the workbook instead of creating a new one, and need to add a new worksheet with formulas to the workbooks before copying data, but those are bonus questions. First:

The macro only opens a new workbook, then skips everything after

```
Do While FileName <> "".
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

To clarify, there *are*, in fact, excel files in the test folder.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I assume you have obeyed `' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.` and changed `FolderPath = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Test_Summary_Folder"` to point to a real folder?

Comment: Yes, that is my real folder, I just took out the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a backslash:
Try

```
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.xl*")
```

Comment: That resulted in a runtime error because it didn't find a specific file the name of which I have no idea how it came up with, but it gave me an idea and adding a backslash after the folder path instead solved the problem.

Comment: @Rodario What you're describing should in effect result in the exact same path strings as would FunThomas' solution.

Comment: @Inarion Yet somehow it doesn't.